# Reindex jar and Elasticsearch

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, jar

2.3.2 jar with ElasticSearch-2.3.4 for using UpdateByQuery plugin when I'm trying to execute the code, it is showing me

> failed to load bundle
>   [file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/antlr4-runtime-4.5.1-1.jar,
>   file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/asm-5.0.4.jar,
>   file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/asm-commons-5.0.4.jar,
>   file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/lang-expression-2.3.4.jar,
>   file:/D:/elasticsearch-2.3.4/modules/lang-expression/lucene-expressions-5.5.0.jar]
>   due to jar hell

When I remove the reindex jar though I'm not getting the error but my updatebyquery is facing an issue. Is there any solution, should I change it to Maven, if I change so, will there be a conflict in the dependency?

Comment: How do you manage your dependencies now?

Comment: i manually add jars

Comment: Although I am not sure what causes this "jar hell", it seems to be a good idea to start to use dependency management, like Maven or Gradle. Jar hell probably means that you include overlapping jars, which can easily happen if you do everything manually.

Comment: Okay Meier,thank you